# ngrx with models that rely heavily on setters

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm migrating to angular an app that has massive logic in properties. This logic is mostly calculations but there are other weirder things. Being an OOP guy I trully believe setters is the perfect place for such logic, but then I came into the angular world and furthermore im trying to use NgRx and I just dont see how to make all these paradigms play nice.

I know stackoverflow doesnt like asking many questions so I'll ask first the main one.

My current approach is to retrieve json objects from the server and then use this data to instantiate "real" classes where the setter logic is defined. 
So,
Whats the ngrx way to do this? 
NgRx doesnt like your objects to be more than serializable structures with no logic, but I DO need these properties in the models to be there. Where else would you put entity related logic otherwise?

As a final note, this system is for data anaysis and its classes perform lots of calculations just as the properties are setted. Each property might impact many others. This logic cannot be in components as these entities are used all over the app (in forms, grids, charts and even drag and drop views, and always reuse the same logic). I dont seem to find a way not-to use property setters.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This logic should probably live in the reducers or action creators.
If it's logic to display data, it's best to add it in selectors.

The redux docs has a section which goes more in depth at [How should I split my logic between reducers and action creators? Where should my “business logic” go?](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go)

> Now, the problem is what to put in the action creator and what in the reducer, the choice between fat and thin action objects. If you put all the logic in the action creator, you end up with fat action objects that basically declare the updates to the state. Reducers become pure, dumb, add-this, remove that, update these functions. They will be easy to compose. But not much of your business logic will be there. If you put more logic in the reducer, you end up with nice, thin action objects, most of your data logic in one place, but your reducers are harder to compose since you might need info from other branches. You end up with large reducers or reducers that take additional arguments from higher up in the state.
>
> Find the balance between these two extremes, and you will master Redux.

Comment: So this means no more 'smart' model classes with logic in their properties getters and setters? So how do you make the app show the binding in real time? suppose I have a "birthdate" property and an "Age" property and then when you pick your birthdate, the ui reacts by showing the calculated age. Do I have to delegate that into the redux pattern as well?